# How to prevent Firefox DOMException error on caches.keys()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise, key, domexception

`caches.keys()` throws an error in Private Mode in Firefox (version 89):

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure.

To see the full error, run `console.log(caches.keys());` in the Firefox DevTools console.

How may this be coded to avoid the error & rejection of the Promise?